# Offline coding with leafletjs

Tags: leaflet

I will be offline (for mapping purposes) for a few weeks, but would like to continue working on my projects. Is there a way I can develop a leafletjs app while offline? I don’t want to create an offline map storage as I really don’t want to look at the maps. I just want leafletjs to not throw any errors while I code other (non-map) parts of the app.

***update:*** to be clear, I want to be able to work with markers, coordinates, zoom, pan, etc. Just don't have to actually view the map tiles as there would be no connection to retrieve the maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do *not* add a `TileLayer`. That way, you won't make network requests to fetch the basemaps.

Another alternative is to download just one map tile (e.g. https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png), save somewhere in your computer, and have a `TileLayer` pointing at the file in your computer, like:

```
L.tileLayer('file://home/ivan/projects/whatever/tile-0.png',{
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 18,
    maxNativeZoom: 0
}).addTo(map);
```

It will probably look like crap, but at least you'll have *something* to show as a basemap, even if it's just one map tile.